# How to unzip only 1 file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, zip

I was looking around and I could find only the piece of code that would extract an entire dir, but how can I extract only one specific file?

Is there a way to adapt this?

```
def extract_zip(file, destination)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)

  Zip::File.open(file) do |zip_file|
    zip_file.each do |f|
      fpath = File.join(destination, f.name)
      zip_file.extract(f, fpath) unless File.exist?(fpath)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you know the name of the file you want to extract?  You can stop the `each` before the extract happens.

Comment: Yes, I know the exact name.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to find your file inside zip, using [Zip::File#find_entry](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyzip/rubyzip/Zip/File#find_entry-instance_method)

```rb
def extract_zip(archive, destination, file_name)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)

  Zip::File.open(archive) do |zip_file|
    if zip_file.find_entry(file_name)
      fpath = File.join(destination, file_name)
      zip_file.extract(file_name, fpath) unless File.exist?(fpath)
    end
  end
end
```